# Does differing meta descriptions on pages that share a canonical tag harm SEO

Tags: seo, canonical-url, meta-tags

Consider the following scenario. There is a single dynamic page that loads different information and meta descriptions based on a query string where there is also a cononical tag so that the query string is not considered as a different page for SEO purposes.

Some content on the page is static like the H1 etc. so that is why there is a cononical tag to avoid duplicate H1s for SEO. Yet there is still dynamic content which we want to provide to a search engine for better search results.

Does this break some search engine rules or negatively effect SEO?

I am thinking there must be some confliction between the fact that the cononical tag says to Google/Bing that there is a single page yet the dynamic content loads different meta information and other content. Surely this would somehow break the different meta descriptions usefullness?

Comment: The description meta tag carries no weight in search. So there is no harm.

Comment: @closetnoc I disagree with your statement that description meta tag carries no weight in search. I believe that this meta tag reports information visible to the user in the SERP. Read more https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en ++ https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624 ++ https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description

Comment: I second the motion. The meta description tag is a very important factor in SEO.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. The description meta tag, will be indexed, however, never weighted in the index for search queries. In other words, it is a data element within the schema, however, no query statement references the description meta tag. The fact that search terms are highlighted is a result of building the SERP as a last step. No search will ever *match* against the description meta tag. The only effect is in SERP user performance. Full stop.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to avoid dynamic pages (as much as possible). If it's a cart page or comment page, make sure to block this one off the robots.txt to avoid duplicate issues.

Comment: canonical tags solve duplicate content problems just as well as blocking pages in robots.txt.   This answer doesn't address the question of whether or not different meta descriptions on canonical pages are a problem.